# Hibernate - map a column to an enum type (values not ordinals)

Tags: java, hibernate, enumeration, lookup-tables

I found a few similar questions here but not quite the same.

If the values of my enum are not ordinals how can I map a class field to that enum type?

--- DB level - lookup table values

```
insert into ShowInfoLookup(ID, Name) values (0 | 64, 'Hide (auto set by the system)');

insert into ShowInfoLookup(ID, Name) values (1 | 64, 'Show (auto set by the system)');

insert into ShowInfoLookup(ID, Name) values (0 | 128, 'Hide (manually set)');

insert into ShowInfoLookup(ID, Name) values (1 | 128, 'Show (manually set)');
```

--- Java code of the enum

```
package com.test.constants;

public enum ShowInfoLookup {

    Invalid(0),
    HideAutoSet(Value.HIDE | Value.AUTO_SET), // 64
    ShowAutoSet(Value.SHOW | Value.AUTO_SET), // 65
    HideManuallySet(Value.HIDE | Value.MANUALLY_SET), // 128
    ShowManuallySet(Value.SHOW | Value.MANUALLY_SET); // 129

    private static class Value {
        private static final int HIDE = 0; // false - hide
        private static final int SHOW = 1; // true - show
        private static final int AUTO_SET = 64;
        private static final int MANUALLY_SET = 128;
    }

    private int value = 0;

    private ShowInfoLookup(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static ShowInfoLookup getInstance(int value) {
        for (ShowInfoLookup type : ShowInfoLookup.values()) {
            if (value == type.value) {
                return type;
            }
        }

        return Invalid;
    }

}
```

--- Hibernate Entity class that I have, I know EnumType.ORDINAL won't work here

```
public class Item {

    @Column(name ="ShowAnalystInfo", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private ShowInfoLookup showInfo;

}
```

Comment: You could create a hibernate `UserType`. Similar example for a custom enum mapping [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeforpersistingaTypesafeEnumerationwithaVARCHARcolumn).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks but sounds kind of an overkill to me. Isn't there any simpler way? I mean, something like a generic RatingUserType :) which would work for all kinds of enums not just for the Rating enum.

Comment: Sure, you could mark the `enum` in the entity as `@Transient`, add another integer field to represent the `enum`'s value to persist, and synchronize both fields in the getters/setters or using entity lifecycle methods.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen OK, thanks, I will think about it. I've also just found this: http://www.gabiaxel.com/2011/01/better-enum-mapping-with-hibernate.html. Sounds straight to the point but also requires more work.

Comment: The generic `RatingUserType` idea should also be more or less doable. As long as all your `enum`s extend a common interface.